# Authorization_RequestDenied in Production app but not in Test app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web API with an Angular frontend.  It's a multi-tenant application. I validate their login abilities by adding `validIssuers` to the `web.config` and to the `TokenValidationParameters` in `startup.auth`.

An admin user from each organization needs to grant permissions to my app in order to log in. Once logged in, I call Microsoft Graph in order to import all users from their organization into my database to mark them as valid users.

They have already granted permissions to my application.

I have a test app and a prod app.  My permissions were granted to all users for both apps in exactly the same way.

I authorize the graph api like this:

```
 public GraphServiceClient AuthGraph(string tid, string groupId)
        {
            try
            {
                var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"];
                var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientSecret"];
                var tenantID = tid;

                IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                     .Create(clientId)
                     //.WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                     .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                     .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                     .Build();

                ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);


                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
                return graphClient;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

I call the graph like this:

GraphServiceClient graphClient = AuthGraph(tid, groupId);

```
        var graphUsers = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()                   
            .GetAsync();
```

Everything works fine but in the test app but in the production app, the Microsoft fails:

```
Status Code: Forbidden 
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 
 Code: Authorization_RequestDenied 
 Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

If I hardcode the authorization values to be the test app permissions, the calls to Graph work.

The strangest part is that I have one client that did *not* grant any login permissions to my test app.  So he can't log in at all to test app, but Microsoft Graph is working fine for him on the prod app. *This makes no sense at all to me!*

[image]

Comment: There isn't a lot of information to go on here. Please add an example failing Prod and working Test token as well as the specific API(s) you're calling.

Comment: What kind of examples can I show you for working?  It works and I know that because it imports new users to my database.  The other one fails and I’ve posted my error above.   What kind of token do you want me to share with you?  Obviously not the value...

Comment: For your test app, have your granted the permissions and grant user/admin consent to the application? You can check the token by using https://jwt.io/, see if the permissions are listed in the token.

Comment: @TonyJu I see at jwt.io the permissions that I gave to my angular app listed there, not the permissions I gave to my c# web api app (which the the one that calls the graph api - but the token i think is requested from angular)

Comment: @Leah I see. So you registered two applications in Azure portal. Front app got access to your webapi app. webapi app got access to graph api, right?

Comment: yes.  and i did this process for both test and prod

Comment: @Leah Have you grant user/admin consent to the graph permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198157/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-leah).

Comment: Please kindly show the request and response, including the access_token in the Authorization header.